# What's the most efficient way to level up in multiplayer?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In Tomb Raider multiplayer, weapons, skills, characters, and other things are unlocked as one levels up.
I just saw a video explaining how to farm XP and Salvage (a sort of currency to buy certain unlockables) in a solo, private match. So for an answer, I'm also OK with editing the game files instead of needlessly grinding by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, it's to play a solo, private match of Rescue and grind breaking wooden crates as Solarii and completing objectives as Survivors.
Even faster with friends: http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/tomb-raider/191333-multiplayer-600-000xp-hour-prestige-4-15-20hours-coop-method-alexstunts.html

Update: So, I've finally bitten the bullet and did some grinding via solo Rescue. Here are my notes and tips:

- Chasm is the most time-vs.-score-efficient map to grind on. Higher range: 49.8903509 points/XP per second = 2993.42105/minute.
- A medkit can be thrown with primary fire.
- Cancel the ending animation of a throw with a roll/evade/sprint.
- Falling releases the medkit.
- Be mindful of the lay of the home zone for the way that the medkit will slide.
- The "Delivery boy" bonus (+1000) is awarded for retrieving three medkits (and is only awarded once per round).
- Start as the Survivors faction.
- XP is saved at half-time, so it's OK to exit to menu at that point. XP is not saved if the match is quit before half-time.
- It's possible to retrieve 20 medkits within 20 minutes. I average ~8.5 minutes for a full iteration ("Start game" to "Start game") on Chasm.
- Setting the goal to and retrieving 20 medkits at a time maximizes efficiency.
- Level 27 is when the "Second Wind" offensive skill is unlocked. It seems to double sprint stamina. This is useful for medkit runs (reaching).
- The three game settings to make sure of, when repeating games, are: faction (Survivors) and medkits (20).
- Throw the kit from the lower wooden platform, if coming from higher, having thrown it to that position from the higher wooden platform. It'll land in the zone if thrown from the lower wooden platform, but it rarely does from the higher wooden platform, necessitating jumping down and picking it up again.
- Run back to a central position after returning one.
- If you do happen to get in a situation where the medkit is on the ground beside the home zone, it may be faster to walk it in instead of performing an adjacent throw.